# TIFF file opens in ArcMap but not in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, arcmap, geotiff-tiff, display

I have a TIFF file that opens in ArcMap but it is blank when opened in QGIS. QGIS log gives this message

> Could not reproject layer extent: Could not transform bounding box to target CRS

In ArcGIS the CRS is

[image]

In QGIS I am using the equivalent CRS

proj string:`+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=84 +k=0.9999 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=evrst30 +towgs84=293.17,726.18,245.36,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs`

WKT:

```
PROJCRS["unknown",
    BASEGEOGCRS["unknown",
        DATUM["Unknown based on Everest 1830 ellipsoid",
            ELLIPSOID["Everest 1830",6377276.345,300.8017,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                    ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8901]]],
    CONVERSION["unknown",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",84,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9999,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
```

Comment: Setting to ESRI:102306 had no effect